# Cross dissolving images with js

Tags: javascript, transition

I'm trying to set up a menu in which every submenu item displays an image in a same box on hover;

```
var i = 0;
while (i < imageS.length) { /* select menu items */
  imageS[i].onmouseover = function() { /* image source (menu item) mouseover */
    imageD.style.display = "block"; /* show container */
    var ops = this.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src; /* find new image url */
      imageD.style.background = "url(" + ops + ") no-repeat left"; /* set new image in the background */
      imageD.style.backgroundSize = "cover"; /* set background size */
    setTimeout(function() { /*
    imageD.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src = ops; /* set new image in the img tag */
      imageD.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].style.transition = "opacity 0.5s linear"; /* fade in transition */
      imageD.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].style.opacity = "1"; /* fade in */
    }, 500);
  }
  imageS[i].onmouseout = function() { /* image source (menu item) mouseover */
    imageD.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].style.transition = "opacity 0.5s linear"; /* fade out transition */
    imageD.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].style.opacity = "0"; /* fade out */
    imageD.style.display = "none"; /* hide container */
  };
  i++;
}
```

you can see it functioning here: https://ilcastellovolante.it/?cmp_bypass=c81630e1be750b5840512f60da8adb10#

there is a little flickr when transition ends, anyone knows why?
thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 0):

You're running a css animation and calling display:none on the same element at the same time. That might be causing the artifact. Since you're setting opacity to 0 you don't need to also set display:none. Does it change when you remove that line?

```
imageS[i].onmouseout = function() { /* image source (menu item) mouseover */
    imageD.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].style.transition = "opacity 0.5s linear"; /* fade out transition */
    imageD.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].style.opacity = "0"; /* fade out */
    // REMOVE :: imageD.style.display = "none"; /* hide container */
  };
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer =) 
I've tried to remove that line, but the image container remain visible,
that's because I'm using background and img in order to get cross-dissolving transition.
Unfortunately background opacity do not exist!